# Using Python to create a very large binary frequency matrix to run collaborative filtering

Tags: python

I'm trying to run collaborative filtering on a large data set of med codes where each patient has 2 or more diagnoses. There are ~291K patients, and there are ~8K unique codes. In order to run CF on this data, I need to create a binary frequency matrix where each unique code is a column and there is a 0 or 1 in each patient's row and column if the disease is present or not.

The problem is this data set has ~2.3 billion cells and my laptop with 16gb of RAM can't process it. I tried it in R using the reshape package and it crashes. I wrote code in Python (below)  .If I subset the data to 500 patients, it takes around 24 hours to process. Does anyone have a better way to do this? I'm wondering if the loop within a loop structure is too inefficient? Or should I apply `sparseMatrix` in R somehow to this data?

list samples:

```
subset_patients =
[['1510395', 'R31', 'N359', 'I639', 'C440', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA'], ['1275226', 'T810', 'N813', 'N393', 'M8417', 'M679', 'M1997', 'L600', 'K529', 'R634', 'R15', 'N811', 'K573', 'K571', 'K222', 'D120', 'A099', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA'], ...... ]

sorted_codes = ['A009', 'A010', 'A011', 'A014', 'A020', 'A021', 'A022', 'A028', 'A029', ... ]
```

my code:

```
bin_freq_matrix = pd.DataFrame(0, index = np.arange(len(subset_patients)), columns = sorted_codes)

count = -1
for row in subset_patients:  #subset_patients is a small list of the patients
    for col in row:
        if col in sorted_codes:  #sorted_codes is the unique codes list
            count = count+1
            bin_freq_matrix.at[count, col]=1

print(bin_freq_matrix.head())
```

NEWEST VERSION:

```
subset_patients = patients[0:1]

def marking(row):
    # here the traverse is in the natural order of columns
    hots = {col for col in row if col in sorted_codes_set}
    # here as well there are no jumps around the memory
    return [1 if col in hots else 0 for col in sorted_codes]

bin_freq_matrix = pd.DataFrame(subset_patients).apply(marking)

print(bin_freq_matrix)
for x in bin_freq_matrix[1]:
    if x==1:
        print("yes")
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO! Indeed you could use a slightly more optimal solution here. There are at least few things you can optimize. Let's look at them step by step moving towards a more comprehensive use of `pandas` funtionality.

1. Optimize the body of the loop
   Interestingly, you do not need to change the actual code constructing the matrix much. It is enough to change the definition of the data structure to make your code so much more efficient! The following line of code:

   if col in sorted_codes:  #sorted_codes is the unique codes list

takes a significant performance toll on the operation due to **linear** ([big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)) characteristics of presence test for lists compared to sets (**logarithmic** characteristics) which you can easily use by changing the definition of `sorted_codes` copy you use to check if value exists to:

```
sorted_codes_set = set(sorted_codes)
```

Sorting the list does not help unless you use [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). It has the same characteristics as sets but you would have to implement the search yourself. The choice is easy: sets.

---

2. Removal of unnecessary operations from the loop.
   The code in the loop is going to be repeated billions of times (in your case) so it should be maximally optimized.

The following line changes the dataframe in the random order which is a bad idea because `pandas` is optimized for sequential access and can be orders of magnitude slower otherwise:

```
bin_freq_matrix.at[count, col]=1
```

---

3. Use `apply` and a function instead of the `for` loop. This is likely to bring the largest gain.

The final piece of code:

```
def marking(row):
    # here the traverse is in the natural order of columns
    hots = {col for col in row if col in sorted_codes_set}
    # here as well there are no jumps around the memory
    return [1  if col in hots else 0 for col in sorted_codes]

bin_freq_matrix = pd.DataFrame(subset_patients).apply(marking)
```

Comment: @datascienceman1 - if you found it helpful please mark as an answer and upvote.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for the assistance. I figured that someone with an advanced CS background could solve this issue. I apologize for the response taking a day.. I really want to understand what's going on in your code and I'm thinking about it. I don't have a lot of experience with functions yet, but it looks like the function followed by apply is doing the work of the entire loop, creating the matrix a row at a time? The problem is I'm getting an invalid syntax error on your return statement for some reason. Trying to figure out why. Is it because I'm running 2.7? Thanks again..

Comment: Yes, it is likely due to my use of Python 3 syntax. It is also a generally faster choice. I suggest you try it too.

Comment: sorry previous comment was a mess due to loss of indentation.. I posted an edit above containing the list error

Comment: I have revised my answer. There was a minor mistake where I assumed subset_patients to be a pandas `DataFrame`.

Comment: ok so I reduced my subset_patients down to just 1 patient to test this. This particular patient has 6 med codes. Your code is producing a bin_freq_matrix object that is 82 x 8,089. 82 lists of mostly 0s. It should be 1 x 8,089 with 1s in each position for each column. I'll keep working on this. Thanks..

Comment: There is an error in the code you posted as an adapted form for Python 2. I corrected the code in the question.

Comment: sorry I should have updated to my newest version of code.. it's posted above. I wrote a loop below just to count the number of codes to test it.

Comment: I'm stuck at this point. I'm trying to figure out why your code generates an 82 x 8,089 size data frame from a list of patients that is 1 x 82. The solution should be a 1 x 8,089 data frame where each unique code is a 1 in that column, else 0. I'll keep working on this in the meantime and post an update if I figure it out. Thanks